# SQL - Find average interval between rows in the timestamp column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, average

In the PostgreSQL and MySQL tables, I have a timestamp column that indicates the data import timestamp. It's based on some scheduled interval. I need to find the avg(or approximate) time interval for the loads.

```
2021-04-18 06:10:26 | Loaded
2021-04-19 00:10:32 | Loaded
2021-04-19 01:10:26 | Loaded
2021-04-19 02:40:24 | Loaded
2021-04-19 04:10:20 | Loaded
2021-04-18 11:10:24 | Loaded
2021-04-18 20:40:28 | Loaded
2021-04-18 00:10:25 | Loaded
2021-04-18 01:10:22 | Loaded
2021-04-18 01:40:22 | Loaded
2021-04-18 13:40:24 | Loaded
2021-04-18 14:10:21 | Loaded
```

Here, approximately every 30mins, the data gets loaded.

I want to write SQL to get this. (in PostgreSQL and MySQL)

I tried this,

`select avg(starttime)` but its showing,

```
Invalid operation: function avg(timestamp without time zone) does not exist;
```

Comment: You should include details about the attempts that you've made so far.  The purpose of StackOverflow is not for someone to do your work for you - it's to assist you when you encounter errors, or problems that you are struggling to overcome (not having done anything yet is not an example of a problem you are struggling to overcome)

Comment: I tried the avg, but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL8.0 and PostgreSQL:

```
with cte as
(
   select timestamp_column- lead(timestamp_column) over (order by timestamp_column) time_diff
   from tablename
) 
select avg(time_diff) from cte
```

For older version of MySQL

```
select avg(time_diff) from
       (
       select timestamp_column- (select min(timestamp_column)from tablename tn
       where  tn.timestamp_column>t.timestamp_column) time_diff
       from tablename t
       )t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate the average of a timestamp - after all what is the average of "Monday Afternoon, Tuesday morning and Thursday at 5"?

You need to average the *difference* between the timestamps. In Postgres subtracting one timestamp from another yields an `interval` and on that you can apply the `avg()` aggregate. To get the difference, you can use a window function:

The following is for Postgres.

```
select avg(diff)
from (
   select starttime - lag(starttime) over (order by starttime) as diff
   from the_table
) t
```

For MySQL, you need to find the equivalent operator to calculate the difference between two timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

The the simplest method is:

```
select (max(starttime) - min(starttime)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t;
```

Neither subqueries nor window fucntions are needed for this calculation.